# Directory listing: 403 Forbidden nginx

Tags: nginx

Preciso de ajuda, eu comecei a usar o Nginx agora, tava pesquisando sobre ai resolvi testar ele, e eu não sei configurar ele corretamente, mas eu queria habilitar pesquisa de diretório. Na documentação dele é (`AutoIndex: on`) mas uso isso, não aparece, da erro 403. O Nginx está no `C:/`, mas eu configurei ele pra fica direcionado na minha pasta `C:/projetos`. Se alguém souber como que eu resolvo isso.

Código de configurar dele:

```
worker_processes  1;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }

    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        sendfile        on;


        server {
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost;

            root C:\Project ;
            index index.html index.htm index.php;

            location / {
                autoindex on;
            }
            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root   html;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Boa tarde, conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Bom dia, consegui sim, era muito simples, o caminho de pasta tava incorreto.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de `root C:\Project ;` use assim `root C:/Project;`, recomendo usar dentro de `location / {` (assim como é na configuração padrão). Parece que está tentando configurar ele com PHP, note que geralmente usamos fastcgi, um exemplo (leia os comentários seguidos por `#` acaso tenha algum duvida referente ao uso):

```
worker_processes  1;

# Gera logs de erro
error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   C:/Project;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            autoindex on;
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redireciona páginas de erro para páginas estaticas /50x.html (no root)
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # Configura o php
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou, preciso ter algum arquivo index dentro do diretório? porque só queria navegar entre as pasta, parecido com Apache, desse jeito: http://www.nacaolivre.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/list-directory-apache.jpg

Comment: é concordo com você desculpe, continua no mesmo erro "403 Forbidden".

Comment: Acho que sim, quando acesso o log, ele me informa erro de permissão, você sabe como eu arrumo isso ?

Comment: Mesmo erro 403, acho que vou ter que pesquisar mais a fundo esse caso

Comment: @GuilhermeAlmeida O usuário que está rodando o Ngnix está com algum "bloqueio", você está rodando ele como administrador? Em que pasta o o Ngnix está instalado?

Comment: estou rodando ele como administrador, está na pasta C:/Ngnix

Comment: @GuilhermeAlmeida `c:/nginx`? Qual versão?

Comment: versão nginx 1.9.2

Comment: Tente uma coisa primeiro, mova a pasta projetc e a pasta ngnix para uma pasta chamada wnmp, por exemplo: `c:\wnmp\nginx` e `c:\wnmp\project` e edite os arquivo ngnix.conf e tente executar o servidor novamente. Se o problema persistir, por favor reinicie o windows e tente novamente. @GuilhermeAlmeida